# GIT post-commit hook not working properly

Tags: git, githooks

This is the hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script that is called after a successful
# commit is made.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-commit".

revisioncount=`git log --oneline -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
echo "<?php \$_v = md5('$revisioncount');" > "../../revision"
echo $revisioncount
```

Basically what it does is save the last commit sha1 to a file.

If i do commit i see the following:

```
$ git commit -a -m "chore: test hook."
7bd2399
[develop 7bd2399] chore: test hook.
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

but the file isn't updated. If i run the hook manually instead it does work:

```
/project/.git/hooks/post-commit
```

and it saves the output to the target file. What's the problem here?

Comment: Since you use a relative path to the file, I'd start by verifying that the working directory for the hook is as you expect.  If you're using a current version of git and the repo is non-bare, then I believe it will run with cwd as the root of the work tree.  (Since you used an absolute path when you talk about manually triggering the script, I can't tell if that's what you expect or not...)

Comment: Check file "project/../../revision".

Comment: You are right, working directory was at project root so my file ended up in project/../../revision. Thanks